# Filling current database with records from another database under certain conditions

Tags: vba, ms-access

First of all, I'm very new with coding, so please bear with me, secondly;

I am currently trying to draw records from another database inside a network into my database. This has proved to be a little troublesome, because I would want to fill all fields in all tables that have the same primary key.

My current code looks like this

```
varPrimaryKey = InputBox("Specify primary key:")
strPrimaryKey = module1.Item1

If Not varPrimaryKey = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Get data from: " & varPrimaryKey)

    If Not (tdf.Name Like "MSys*" Or tdf.Name Like "~*") Then
        For Each tdf In externalDb.TableDefs
            For Each fld In tdf.Fields

                db.Execute ("INSERT INTO CurrentDb.fld.Name SELECT fld.Name FROM tdf.Name WHERE fld.Name = 'Value' AND varPrimaryKey = 'Value'")

            Next fld
        Next tdf
    End If
End If
```

Right now I'm getting a type mismatch error from .CurrentDb , but I have a feeling that there's something else wrong with this code too, just can't put my finger on  it. If someone could help, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Missing some spaces in `" SELECT..."` and `" WHERE..."`

Comment: There are many things wrong with this code. If I understand correctly, you only want to copy a single record from that other database? Or do you mean with _I would want to fill all fields in all tables that have the same primary key._ that you want the primary key column to have a certain name?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I was afraid I didn't explain it correctly! I meant that I would want to draw ALL records from ALL tables that have the same primary key ID as the one that the user has entered inside an input box.

Comment: `CurrentDb` returns an object, not a string that you could use to build dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Andre what should I use instead of CurrentDb in order to reference my current database?

Comment: Why not use linked tables and filter tables according to user input? This is not how a database should be run. Duplicated data and storage should be avoided. Use only **one** backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reconsider this entire approach. For user application needs, databases should not be copied versions of each other as gathered from above comment:

> I meant that I would want to draw ALL records from ALL tables that
>   have the same primary key ID as the one that the user has entered
>   inside an input box

One of the central tenets of a relational database is to avoid duplication of data. Plus, if users add/edit data it will reflect live on the system. Data transference between databases should only be run for migration purposes where one is to be archived and other for production.

---

With that said, consider the following steps to build your user application:

1. [Link all needed tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-link-to-data-in-another-access-database-095ab408-89c7-45b3-aac2-58036e45fcf6) from network database. The GUI dialog allows a *Select All* feature or holding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and/or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> for multiple tables.
2. Build a temp table to hold current user's primary key and insert data value via VBA. This is the only table to hold data (one column/one row structure) in application database. See below steps:

   Create a table with code or via Table Design *(one row/one column)*

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE TmpPrimaryKey (
       PrimaryID Long
   )
   ```

   Append using user input as below shows with parameterization with VBA. This code should be run regularly for any change to PK. Ideally, run this at startup of application.

   ```vb
   Dim qdef As QueryDef
   Dim strSQL As String
   Dim varPrimaryKey As Variant

   varPrimaryKey = InputBox("Specify primary key:")

   ' CLEAN OUT TEMP TABLE
   CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM TmpPrimaryKey", dbFailOnError

   ' APPEND TO TEMP TABLE 
   strSQL = "PARAMETERS [PkParam] LONG;" _ 
               & " INSERT INTO TmpPrimaryKey (PrimaryID) VALUES ([PkParam])"

   Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)
   qdef![PkParam] = varPrimaryKey
   qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

   Set qdef = Nothing
   ```
3. Create a filtered query for every linked table aligning to *TmpPrimaryKey* (i.e., the target primary key). Doing so, the user will only see such records. Use these queries for forms/reports recordsources or module recordsets.

   Queries can use the `JOIN`, `IN`, `EXISTS` clauses such as below examples of separate SQL statements. Tables below would be linked tables from network database (step #1).

   Query1

   ```sql
   SELECT src.* 
   FROM [Table1] src
   INNER JOIN TmpPrimaryKey tmp ON src.ID = tmp.PrimaryID;
   ```

   Query2

   ```sql
   SELECT src.* 
   FROM [Table2] src
   WHERE src.ID IN (SELECT PrimaryID FROM TmpPrimaryKey);
   ```

   Query3

   ```sql
   SELECT src.* 
   FROM [Table3] src
   WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT 1 FROM TmpPrimaryKey tmp WHERE src.ID = tmp.PrimaryID);
   ```

   Because you potentially have many tables, build above SQL queries in VBA loop using [TableDefs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195790.aspx) and [QueryDefs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194892.aspx). NOTE: Below loop routine to create queries should be run only **once**.

   ```vb
   Dim tdef As TableDef
   Dim qdef As QueryDef
   Dim strSQL As String

   ' LOOP THROUGH ALL TABLES OF APP DB (I.E., LINKED TABLES)
   For Each tdef in CurrentDb.TableDefs
       If tdef.Name <> "TmpPrimaryKey" And tdef.Name Not Like "MSys*" Then
           ' ASSUMING EACH TABLE'S PK IS NAMED ID
           strSQL = "SELECT src.* FROM [" & tdef.Name & "] src"  _
                     & " INNER JOIN TmpPrimaryKey tmp ON src.ID = tmp.PrimaryID;"    

           ' NAME EACH QUERY SAME AS TABLE WITH "Q_PK" SUFFIX
           Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(tdef.Name & "Q_PK", strSQL)
           Set qdef = Nothing
       End If
   Next tdef

   Set tdef = Nothing
   ```

   Again, set all needed application objects (forms, reports, modules, etc.) to point to these queries as the data sources and not linked tables, holding all data. Queries should be updateable for user to add/edit records.

---

From there, distribute copies of this application database to all users in a frontend/backend split architecture, maintaining **one** centralized and normalized database and many app files that hold **no** data (except of course, the temp PK value).

[image: Split Database Design]

Comment: I can't really use this solution because the database has +-100 tables, so I can't exactly list them inside a query... Or maybe I misunderstood what you meant. The solution I'm trying to build would only duplicate certain data from the tables of the network database, allow the user to make the changes they need, then save the data into the network database. At the end of the session the tables would be cleared out in the desktop database.

Comment: Do not do this. Have desktop connect directly to network database and link to all needed tables. Even if it is 100+ tables. As I have relayed above this is known as front-end/back-end split and practically all modern day web/desktop apps run like this with data centralized on server and apps interact with data. You can build queries even link tables in a loop.

Comment: Alright, I do see your point. I would like to try how this works, but I don't quite understand the SQL you wrote. Are these all SELECT clauses supposed to be in the same query? Or are they examples of different queries? (Sorry if this is an incredibly dumb question...)

Comment: Also, I don't think these queries insert any information inside the app's tables? When I run the SQL I can see some random values, but when the VBA code is ran, the tables remain empty.

Comment: See my edit hopefully for clarity, walking you through the process. Simply link tables from network db and then create queries for each table that filters to temporary primary key. Use these queries for forms/reports/modules in app db. **No** data is inserted/copied from *any* table. All queries connect to live network database via linked tables. Forewarning: this process is not for true beginners in MS Access.

Answer (score 1):

You just reference the table you want to INSERT into. What you need is path to the other db. Need to concatenate variables. You don't show declaring and setting variables `db`, `tdf`, `fld`, `externalDB`. Need to swap the `If` and first `For` lines. Your INSERT SELECT will not work the way you think, unless you really want each field inserted into its own record. Consider:

```
For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If Not (tdf.Name Like "MSys*" Or tdf.Name Like "~*") Then

        CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT INTO [" & tdf.Name & "] SELECT * FROM [" & tdf.Name & _
        "] IN 'other db path\filename.accdb' WHERE [Value] = '" & varPrimaryKey & "'")

    End If
Next tdf
```

However, autonumber fields will interfere with this simple INSERT SELECT. Also, fields in both tables must be arranged in same order in table design.

`Value` is a reserved word and really should avoid using reserved words as names for anything. If `Value` is a number data type then eliminate the apostrophe delimiters.

Why have that MsgBox?

But then why all this effort anyway and not just link to the backend tables?

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! Like I said, I'm very new with this and I'm just trying to learn to understand how everything works. The reason why the tables cannot be linked, is because the idea of the feature is to draw only certain information from the online database, so the user can do what they need to do, and once the user is done, the tables would be cleared of records again. So the database in the network is the only one that has the information stored all the time. Also, the MsgBox is just a declaration for the user, nothing more. Anyway thank you, I will try this one instead!

Comment: Right now I'm getting an error of "Too few parameters. Expected 1." when using this line of code. I ran it in a query without the tdf.Name and varPrimaryKey fields, and it ran fine, so the issue is either those or the CurrentDb.Execute. Can't seem to figure it out though...

Comment: Did an edit to my code. I meant to use CurrentDb instead of externalDb. Code all works for me. Make sure your path string is correct and tdf.Name and varPrimaryKey are passing values.